# Bitbucket Link vs Hook (JIRA DVCS Connector Add-on)

Tags: jira, bitbucket

What is difference between a Link and Hook in Bitbucket with regards to linking JIRA issues (and transitioning them through workflow)?  I followed the steps from [Getting Started with Bitbucket and OnDemand](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AOD/Getting+started+with+Bitbucket+and+OnDemand) to set up a link between Bitbucket and JIRA.  This automatically created a POST commit hook service to my repositories.  At bottom of article, there was a link to [Link to a web service](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Link+to+a+web+service) in Bitbucket as if this was an additional/different option.

I stopped at this point and didn't add a Link to my Bitbucket account.  I'm about to go play with a sample repo and JIRA project to see what I can do, but should I be setting up a *Link* as well?

Thanks in advance.